# Trello to quickly move a card to top of another list?

Tags: trello, trello-cards, trello-lists

When we use `Move` action to move a card to a list, the card is placed at the bottom of the list. I want to place the card on top after moved. How to do that?

p.s.
My [google search](https://www.google.com.vn/#q=trello+quickly+move+a+card+to+end+of+another+list) lead me to [trello guide for this issue](http://help.trello.com/article/806-moving-cards-or-lists) though cannot find the content for my `move on top` need.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two things you can do

1. Click move, then specify the position of the card in the destination list

[image: Set Destination Position of Trello Card]

2. The other thing you can do is to temporarily move the card to another list so that the card is visible on your screen. Then scroll to the top of your destination list. Then move the card from it's temporary spot to the top of your destination list.

Comment: The `Position` option is what I missed. Thanks a ton!

Comment: @NamGVU No problem. Yes, it's subtle and sometimes easy to miss.